# корректно получить ключ и его значение

Tags: javascript

Не могу корректно получить ключ и его значение из объекта value  ввида {"ключ": "значение"}  и сравнить его с перемнной bbb

```
var values = {"ключ": "значение"};  // значение {"myonoffswitch-2": "1"};

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var values = JSON.parse(values);

    var bbb = $('#myonoffswitch-' + i).attr('id');  // значение
    var ccc = $('#myonoffswitch-' + i).val();  // значение

    for (var key in values) {
        if (key == bbb) {
            var valInp = el.setAttribute('value', values[key]);
        }
        value = values[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: И почему у вас **'#myonoffswitch-' + i** вне цикла ?

Comment: Он у меня завернут в цикле  for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++) { }  ...просто не стал перегружать вопрос кодом. думал по смыслу ясно будет

Comment: ` var value = JSON.parse(value);` вот эта строчка кода на второй итерации может выкинуть exception. Отформотируйте код нормально, пожалуйста. Укажите значения для всех переменных. Что такое `value`, `values` и `el`?

Comment: Вот именно, что смысл трудно понять по вашему коду, почему у вас два **var bbb=**  и не понятно, что хотите получить в итоге... вы лучше покажите нам HTML и напишите что и куда хотите вставить и при каких условиях, тогда можем показать рабочий пример )) а то так всё каша....

Comment: Данный код не будет работать из-за строчки `var values = JSON.parse(values)`. Откройте консоль у себя и посмотрите, что происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь распарсить объект в объект при помощи JSON.parse().
Эта функция нужна для распарсивания строки в объект.
Путаница возникла из-за того, что объект в JavaScript и JSON-строки очень похожи.

Просто удалите строчку:

```
    var values = JSON.parse(values);
```